# Inventory design management - FIFO / Weighted Average design which also needs historical inventory value

Tags: django, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, inventory-management

I have a database with the following details:

**Product**

```
Name
SKU
UOM (There is a UOM master, so all purchase and sales are converted to base uom and stored in the db)
Some other details
has_attribute
has_batch
```

**Attributes**

```
Name
Details/Remarks
```

**Product-Attribute**

```
Product (FK)
Attribute(FK)
Value of attribute
```

**Inventory Details**

```
#This is added for every product lot bought & quantity available is updated after every sale

Product (FK)
Warehouse (FK to warehoue model)
Purchase Date
Purchase Price
MRP
Tentative sales price
Quantity_bought
Quantity_available
Other batch details if applicable(batch id, manufactured_date, expiry_date)
```

**Inventory Ledger**

```
#This table records all in & out movement of inventory

Product
Warehouse (FK to warehoue model)
Transaction Type (Purchase/Sales)
Quantity_transacted(i.e. quantity purchased/sold)
Inventory_Purchase_cost(So as to calculate inventory valuation)
```

Now, my problem is:

I need to find out the historical inventory cost. For example, let's say I need to find out the value of inventory on 10th Feb 2017, what I'll be doing with the current table is not very efficient: I'll find out current inventory and go back through the ledger for all 1000-1500 SKU and about 100 transactions daily (for each sku) for more than 120 days and come to a value. taht's about 1500*100*120. It's Huge. Is there a better DB design to handle this case?

Comment: Why did anyone downvote it? Atleast provide a reason for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you tested it? 1500*100*120 is not *that* huge. It may be acceptable performance and there is no problem to be solved!

I'm not 100% clear how you compute the value. Do you sum up the InventoryLedger rows for each Product in each Warehouse? Is so, it's easy to put a value on the purchases, but how do you value the sales? I'm going to assume that you value the sales using the Inventory_Purchase_Cost (so it should maybe be called TransactionValue instead).

If you must optimise it, I suggest you could populate a record each day for the valuation of the product in each warehouse. I suggest the following StockValution table could be populated daily and this would allow quick computation of the valuations for any historical day.
[image: QuickDatagbaseDiagrams SO 43884570]

Diagram made using [QuickDBD](https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/schema/6Gh7cYc0MkWeM68Gl9-UZA), where I work.

Comment: First thing: I'm loving QuickDB. Secondly, Stock Valuation table has a problem: Instead of storing transaction (that's what a db does), it stores historical data. So, if we need to change some data 10 days back, we need to update all the data of 10 days hence. Let's see how it works out. Thanks either ways!!!